# Nose: Capture script output as well as test output

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

If I put any print statements at the top of my module, not inside any class/function, nothing gets printed while running my test through nose.

```
import os
print 'hi'
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

def make_shapes(canvas):
    """
    Generates shapes. Needs a Canvas instance to add the shapes to
    """
    params = [canvas, Colour(0, 0, 0), 1]
```

placing the print inside the function works though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this is the problem, but you can run `nosetests` with the `-s` argument to prevent capturing of stdout.